# Visual Studio has the type of my XAML control wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I seem to have an issue where Visual Studio thinks a control is a RichTextBlock (which it used to be) but it is now a RichEditBox. As a result it is not accepting it's Document property.

In the screenshot you can see the peek to the definition with the hover over showing the type in Visual Studio (2015)

Any ideas?

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJS7T.png)

Comment: Maybe a clean and build?

Comment: Done that.. closed and re-opened.. Still thinks it's a richtextblock.. It's a pain as I'm moving from WPF desktop app to UWP (It was a richtextbox originally) and it's getting in the way of me finding other compatibility issues

Comment: Strange, Have you tried deleting your obj folders? Also try clearing your VS cache (.vs folder).

Comment: It was in the object cache I think (I assumed that would all get rebuilt in a clean and rebuild).

I changed the name of the Control in XAML and it still was happy in th source code, but when I went to definition it took me to the generated .cs files where it was still a textblock, so I changed it there.. seems ok now, but also doesn''t fill me with confidence I have found and fixed the issue.. I'll see if it happens again!